# jQuery 1.7.1 "on" function does not work with regular Javascript event trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium-webdriver, jquery-events

I register the following function

```
//EDIT: updated
$("#id").on("change", function() {
  alert('xxx');
});
```

In my IE console I did

```
document.getElementById('id').onchange();
```

and it says element this does not have property or value.

I am trying to run automation test using

```
selenium.runScript("document.getElementById('id').onchange();");
```

What are ways around this? In IE I get JavaScript error popping up, thus stopping rest of the test.

Comment: Use a color-syntax editor, that's helpful. You'll see this kind of mistake easily. Many are free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks I found the answer. I had to use

```
selenium.runScript($("#id").change());
```

even if I had added the missing quote.

If you register listener with on it doesn't get register by the dom's onchange event.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quote:

```
//$("#id).on("change", function() {
$("#id").on("change", function() {
     alert('xxx');
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a quote in your selector:

```
//    ▼here
$("#id").on("change", function() {
     alert('xxx');
});
```

Comment: yup, and why not just use `$("#id").change(function(e) {` which is the exact same thing but easier to read and keep up with?

Comment: Many people prefer to use `.on()` to the various `.click()`, `.change()` etc functions.  For instance, you can target multiple events with `.on()`.  It also behaves like the old `.live()` function where it affects elements dynamically added to the DOM.

Comment: True, but I prefer to make it a "last possible use" kinda thing in that more often than not, multiple events aren't needing the same function on any single element.  It just seems very overused to me.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close the quotes on `"#id"`

Your code should look like this

```
$("#id").on("change", function() {
     alert('xxx');
 });
```